# After validating a model, how to extract optimal inputs inputs based on a given output?

Tags: classification, prediction, multi-output

I Looked around and could not find a similar question (at least not with the keywords I used).
After I trained and tested a classification model, I understand how I can supply it with a new input to generate a predicted output.
But how can I do the reverse task- supply it with an output and extract the optimal or best input parameters? (i.e. the one that are predicted to generate the given output)?

Answer (score 1):

Some models are better at predicting input from the output. for example decision tree make the classification based on feature value .  it is easy to go back trace from the leaf to the root of the decision tree.  however it is difficult to back trace in Logistic regression. There will be many possible combination of features by which same output can be obtained.